# cgo and pkg-config

Tags: go, graphicsmagick, cgo

I want to run GraphicsMagick with cgo.

```
/*
#cgo pkg-config: GraphicsMagick-config

#include <magick/api.h>

static int gm(int argc, char **argv) {
    int status;
    status = GMCommand(argc, argv);
    return 1-status;
}
*/
```

then I run 'go install', it says:

```
# pkg-config --cflags GraphicsMagick-config
Package GraphicsMagick-config was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `GraphicsMagick-config.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'GraphicsMagick-config' found
exit status 1
```

but I run 'pkg-config GraphicsMagick-config' in shell and it's ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GraphicsMagick-config` script is a separate program rather than a pkg-config resource, which explains the problem.

Also, running pkg-config with a non-option argument seems to fail without printing an error message, which might have confused you.

In addition to this script though, the library does install a `GraphicsMagick.pc` data file for pkg-config.  So you should be able to get your code running with:

```
#cgo pkg-config: GraphicsMagick
```